# How can I programmatically (C++) save the event log file as a CSV?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, windows-xp, event-log

I would like to save the event log to a CSV file, both in Windows XP and Windows 7.

In Windows XP I can manually do it: I open the "Event viewer" (`EVENTVWR` or `EVENTVWR.MSC` on the command line), then for example I right click on the "Application" log, then I choose the contextual menu command "Save log file as" and "CSV (Comma delimited)(*.csv)" and I finally get the log saved on a file.

The file contains **all** the log information: it contains the **full** formatted message for every events.

If you simply launch the contextual menu command "Export list" you will instead get a mere list of event's "metadata" like `Type, Date, Time, Source, Category, Event, User, Computer`.

I browsed the available APIs in Windows XP, that is the [Event Logging Functions (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and I have found that:

1. `BackupEventLog` does not allow me to choose the format of the
   backup file, i.e. it will save in a binary format that to me will be useless.
2. `ReadEventLog` gives me just the metadata via the structure `EVENTLOGRECORD` and the instructions to get the full formatted message with a lot of work:

> The event identifier together with source name and a language
>   identifier identify a string that describes the event in more detail.
>   The strings are used as replacement strings and are merged into the
>   message string to make a complete message. The message strings are
>   contained in a message file specified in the source entry in the
>   registry. To obtain the appropriate message string from the message
>   file, load the message file with the LoadLibrary function and use the
>   FormatMessage function.

Now, it is a lot of work: with the `source` go into the registry (where? I am afraid there are multiple possible places...) to find the resource file name, load the file with `LoadLibrary` and then format the message with `FormatMessage`.

Am I missing something? Is there any shortcut? Why don't Microsoft gives us a plain API to backup the log in CSV format? After all they already wrote the code inside `eventvwr`...

Now I am a bit discouraged and I did not browsed the `Evt*` APIs ([Windows Event Log Functions (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) available since Windows Vista.

Comment: Don't know your context and if C++ is a mandatory choice for you, but using PowerShell and WMI would make your life easier.   Get-EventLog Application -EntryType Error | Select-Object Timegenerated, EntryType, MachineName, Message | Format-Table >.\Desktop\Log.csv

Comment: @DavidBrabant Thank you but unfortunately C++ is a mandatory choice for me.

Comment: @uvts_cvs I think it's not the API functionality, but own written, i.e. just extracting date, time, event id, etc. and writing them sequentially in txt or csv file.