# How can I get in C++ the same behavior of `wevtutil qe Application`?

Tags: c++, windows, event-log, wevtutil

I would like to export the Windows `Application` event log to an XML file.

In the past I asked [How can I programmatically (C++) save the event log file as a CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13642564/15485) with no success.

Today I tried [EvtArchiveExportedLog fails with ERROR_DIRECTORY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3301271/15485) with no success: I get the error `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` instead of `ERROR_DIRECTORY` and I have no idea on how to

> grant access privileges to the calling thread

as suggested in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110631/

The command line `wevtutil qe Application > Application.xml` does exactly what I need and I would like to get the same behavior with C++ code (apart from `system("wevtutil qe Application > Application.xml");`).

Iterating over all the events seems poorly performing https://serverfault.com/a/353439/44612

Comment: Maybe you can try this  [querying-for-event-source-messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/querying-for-event-source-messages)

Comment: Have you tried to run the application with admin privileges?